# Codeigniter Modules

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm putting together a dashboard for a backend to a CMS project made with Codeigniter. There is some navigation in a sidebar and I"m trying to figure out what I need to know making "modules".  I have two types of users. Administrators and basic users. They share the same sidebar navigation. Admins can see all links in the navigation and basic users can only see some. I was trying to look at a few different CMS's to see how they do it and really like how PyroCMS does it with putting together their navigation. However, I"m trying to find out what really tells me what I should makes a module. I know it has its own controllers, models, views and etc. I'm trying to find out with research what I need to know to really know what should I make into a module. Are their questions I should I should be asking myself that will be able to tell me what has the possibility of being a module and what isn't.

[CMS Admin_Controller Line 80](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/2.2/master/system/cms/core/Admin_Controller.php)

Answer (score 0):

Module development with PyroCMS is **the way to go** if you're used to **working in CodeIgniter**.

Becoming acclimated will be intuitive as a CI programmer, create a new module (drop it in your *addons/shared_addons/modules* folder):
https://github.com/pyrocms/sample

And notice how the routing works:
http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/basics/modular-routing

Then take a looksee at MY_Model (*system/cms/core*) that PyroCMS includes. I wrote a few modules before realizing PyroCMS includes a basic model that will save you from writing a lot of extraneous code. Don't worry, you can still always choose extend CI_Model instead if you don't want to use MY_Model for a module.

The more you learn about the mechanics of PyroCMS, the more you realize it has no limits. Unless you're writing trivial apps or just like re-writing code, I wouldn't start any new project in CI because PyroCMS is the more sensible starting point.

If there is something more advanced that the documentation doesn't answer for you. Then SNOOP AROUND! All the core features are built as modules. Check out how they did it in one of the core modules (*system/cms/modules/*). And if you want to change something in the core, you can avoid make any changes to the core by overloading views.

Once you're confident with your ported CI App, I would check out Streams. Streams will dramatically increase the time it takes to write trivial CRUD modules. If you're as happy as I've been with Pyro, you won't mind shelling out the lettuce to buy PyroCMS Pro or Streams.